# Export SQL Query to Excel File with multiple sheets

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, export-to-excel

I have the below query (thanks to stackoverflow) that will loop through a list of groups and give me the permissions the group will have for a category. In Linqpad I can export the result into one Excel sheet, but I was wondering if it was possible to export each group result in the loop to a separate sheet in the Excel file. I was going to try in C# first, but I was wondering if it can be done via SQL or Linqpad as well.

Also, Ad Hoc Distributed Queries are disabled on the server.

```
SELECT GroupId, Name
INTO #GroupTemp
FROM [Group]

DECLARE @Id INT

WHILE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM #GroupTemp
    )
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @Id = GroupId
    FROM #Temp

    SELECT g.NAME AS 'GroupName'
        ,c.NAME AS 'CategoryName'
        ,c.CategoryId
        ,c.ParentCategoryId
        ,p.[Read]
        ,p.Edit
        ,p.[Delete]
        ,p.[Add]
        ,p.Share
        ,p.Admin
    FROM GroupCategoryPermission p
    INNER JOIN [Group] g ON p.GroupId = @Id
    INNER JOIN Category c ON p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
    WHERE g.GroupId = @Id

    DELETE #GroupTemp
    WHERE GroupId = @Id
END
```

Comment: I'm thinking it may be best to dump the result into one sheet and then use a macro to separate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to use an Excel macro after I exported the query from Linqpad. My VBA is a little rusty and I have a couple of small issues that I need to work out (I'm sure there is an easier way than I did it), but this is okay for now. Basically, I searched for every row in column one with GroupName as the value. From there I stored those in an array and used the different in between each for each sheet to be added.

```
Option Explicit

Private Function Sleep()
    Application.Wait Now + 1 / (24 * 60 * 60.0# * 2)
End Function

'Remove 1st row of Sheet 1 and blank rows from sheet
Private Function CheckEmpty()
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets(1).Select()
    Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete()
    Rows("1:1").Select()
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Function

'Function to get the name of the group and name the sheet that name
Private Function NameSheet()
    Dim groupName As String
    groupName = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value
    If Len(groupName) > 31 Then
        groupName = Left(groupName, 31)
        ActiveSheet.Name = groupName
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Name = groupName
    End If
End Function

'This will format the sheet
Private Function FormatSheet()
    Cells.Select()
    With Selection
        .WrapText = False
    End With
    Rows("1:1").Select()
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Cells.Select()
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
        .Columns.AutoFit()
    End With
End Function

'Main sub to separate groups into their own sheets
Sub SplitToSheets()
    'Variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, cell As Range, findString As String
    Dim counter As Long, numbers() As Long, lastRow As Long, firstRow As Long
    'Clean sheet 1
    Worksheets(1).Activate()
    CheckEmpty()
    FormatSheet()
    'Set the range that we will be checking
    firstRow = Rows("1:1").Row
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    rng = Range("A" & firstRow & ":" & "A" & lastRow)
    rng.Select()

    'Set the counter so we loop through array
    counter = 1
    'Loop through array and store row numbers
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "GroupName" Then
            ReDim Preserve numbers(counter)
            numbers(counter) = cell.Row
            'Increase counter by 1
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next

    'Separate groups to sheet using numbers array
    'Variables
    Dim inx As Long, rStart As Long, rEnd As Long, ind As Long
    'Copy first group to new sheet on it's own (need to change logic to avoid separation, eventually)
    rStart = numbers(1)
    rEnd = numbers(2) - 1
    Rows(rStart & ":" & rEnd).Select()
    Selection.Copy()
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Selection.PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)
    NameSheet()
    FormatSheet()
    'Index Counter for looping through array
    ind = 0
    For inx = LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers)
        'Need to loop once and make sure the counter is greater than 1
        If ind > 0 Then
            'Revert to sheet 1
            Worksheets(1).Select()
            'Start row number
            rStart = numbers(ind)
            'End row number
            rEnd = (numbers(ind) - numbers(ind - 1))
            'Selection must start on second group
            If rEnd > 1 Then
                'Select range
                Rows(rStart & ":" & rStart + rEnd).Select()
                'Copy
                Selection.Copy()
                'Add next availble sheet
                Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                'Paste values
                Selection.PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
                xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)
                'Set sheet name and rename to match group
                NameSheet()
                FormatSheet()
                Sleep()
            End If
        End If
        'Increase index by 1
        ind = ind + 1
    Next
    'This deletes the main sheet that we no longer need
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets(1).Delete()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Worksheets(1).Activate()
End Sub

'This macro will give option to seach for sheet
Sub GetSheet()
    Dim SearchData As String
    SearchData = InputBox("Enter 'exact' group name.")
    If SearchData <> vbNullString Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets(SearchData).Activate()
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Unable to find group named: " & SearchData
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```